# jstl if/else doesn't work correctly

Tags: if-statement, jstl

I want my code to do this...

```
<c:if test="${validated != 'Y' }">
    <form:form id="newJob" method="post" action="updateValidated" commandName="jobModel">
        <form:input path="regattaId" type="hidden" />
        <form:input path="job_id" type="hidden" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="label.validated" />
                <td><form:radiobutton path="validated" value="Y" />Yes<form:radiobutton
                            path="validated" value="N" />No</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value='<spring:message code="label.validateJob"/>' hidden="true" />
    </form:form>
</c:if>
<c:else>
    This job is validated
</c:else>
```

Any takers?  Right now it doesn't work.
I think my syntax is correct but I'm very new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the equivalent code is

```
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${validated != 'Y' }">
        <form:form id="newJob" method="post" action="updateValidated"
            commandName="jobModel">
            <form:input path="regattaId" type="hidden" />
            <form:input path="job_id" type="hidden" />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><spring:message code="label.validated" />
                    <td><form:radiobutton path="validated" value="Y" />Yes<form:radiobutton
                            path="validated" value="N" />No</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" class="button"
                value='<spring:message code="label.validateJob"/>' hidden="true" />
        </form:form>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        This job is validated
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Jstl's c:if tag doesn't have a companion c:else tag.  Try c:choose!

Comment: no problem.  and as #JB posted above... check out the documentation! http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html

Answer (score 3):

`<c:else>` doesn't exist, and has never existed. Read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html) of what you're using instead of trying random things.

The correct way, using the JSTL, to have the equivalent of if/else is

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="condition">...</c:when>
    <c:otherwise>...</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```